# Recover lost MySQL password

Tags: mysql, password-recovery

I hate to ask a stupid question like forgetting the password, but this one is really hard to get back. Tried all the methods I can find online, and none is working. Even deleting the database requires my password, which means if I don't get my password back somehow, or reset, I am basically done with using it for my life.

I am using Mac OS 10.10.2 Here is what i have tried: Tried to stop it first, using a script from the oracle site:

```
kill `cat /mysql-data-directory/host_name.pid`
```

...getting no such directory error. I terminated MySQL manually from system preferences, and did the following:

Everyone is saying to use:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

...but it is not working here. No `mysqld_safe` command even exists when I punched it into cmd. Then I digged into the directory files, and used:

```
sudo ./usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

After i did, it still asked for my password! Then I tried to remove sudo:

```
./usr/local/mysql/bin mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

it becomes:

```
fan$ ./mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
./mysqld_safe: line 522: /usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld_safe.pid: Permission denied
awk: i/o error occurred while closing /dev/stdout
 input record number 8, file 
 source line number 1
160204 00:21:13 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/guiyang-Fans-MacBook-Pro.local.err'.
touch: /usr/local/mysql/data/guiyang-Fans-MacBook-Pro.local.err: Permission denied
chmod: /usr/local/mysql/data/guiyang-Fans-MacBook-Pro.local.err: Permission denied
160204 00:21:13 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
./mysqld_safe: line 130: /usr/local/mysql/data/guiyang-Fans-MacBook-Pro.local.err: Permission denied
rm: /tmp/mysql.sock: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/mysql/data/guiyang-Fans-MacBook-Pro.local.pid: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/mysql/data/guiyang-Fans-MacBook-Pro.local.pid.shutdown: Permission denied
```

Please help to save my life with this mess! I really really don't understand why Oracle wants to give me a so sophisticated password in the beginning instead of asking me to set one! I jotted down the password it gave me, which was a combination (&*,<>AaFz0).

I have updated my termination procedures, and it is not working at all. I have used http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html to try to solve the problem. I am getting the same thing,the big chunk of nonsense above.

Here is what I got:

```
/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld_safe.pid: Permission denied
awk: i/o error occurred while closing /dev/stdout
 input record number 1, file 
 source line number 1
160204 01:11:50 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/Fans-MacBook-Pro.local.err'.
touch: /usr/local/mysql/data/Fans-MacBook-Pro.local.err: Permission denied
```

Comment: This is probably a stupid question... but did you *stop* the MySQL instance *before* you tried starting it again (using `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` ? You say it "asks for a password"... you are referring to a subsequent attempt to connect to the database from the mysql command line client (not the password prompt from `sudo`).  I apologize if those are stupid questions. But your question omits any mention of stopping mysql, and doesn't demonstrate how you are attempting to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

1. Add below 2 lines in `my.cnf`

   ```
   skip-grant-tables
   skip-networking
   ```
2. Restart mysql service

   ```
   service mysqld restart
   ```

   Note: if you don't have a service, you can do from `/etc/init.d/`
3. Connect mysql:

   ```
   mysql
   ```
4. Update root password:

   ```
   UPDATE mysql.user 
   SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') 
   WHERE USER='root'; 

   flush privileges"; 
   exit;
   ```
5. Remove newly added lines from `my.cnf` and restart the mysql service.

Permission errors mean you don't have admin permission where you are trying to do the task, so login with admin login first.

Comment: Thanks Zafar. You are right. I need to add the tricky sudo in front of every cmd